# Match if previous line starts with character

Tags: regex, grep, line

I have a file, that looks like this:

```
expression1
- expresson1.1
- expressoion1.2
expression2
-expression2.1
expression3
-expression3.1
-expression3.2
-expression3.3
```

What I want to do is, delete lines 1.2, 3.2 and 3.3, so only lines that do not start with a minus, and the next line remain.

So I tried writing a regex that matches every line starting with a minus where the previous one also started with a minus, and then delete them.

So far, no success. Any hints would be very appreciated.

Comment: What reg expressions did you try to achieve this?

Comment: as always, what have you tried and what regexp-flavor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if an awk solution would be accepted by you, check the one-liner below:

```
awk '/^[^-]/{f=1;print;next;}{if(f && $0~/^-/){print;f=0;}}' yourFile
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "expression1
dquote> - expresson1.1
dquote> - expressoion1.2
dquote> expression2
dquote> -expression2.1
dquote> expression3
dquote> -expression3.1
dquote> -expression3.2
dquote> -expression3.3
dquote> "|awk '/^[^-]/{f=1;print;next;}{if(f && $0~/^-/){print;f=0;}}'
expression1
- expresson1.1
expression2
-expression2.1
expression3
-expression3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/(-.+)\s((-.+)?(\s|))+/g
```

Replacing the matches with:

```
$1\n
```

You can see this regex in action with RegExr [here](http://regexr.com?329ac).

P.S. tough problem, here lookarounds don't work because you don't have fixed length prefixes to match against, while lookbehind (and lookahead) require fixed length strings as pointed out [here](http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/regex/regex-lookarounds.html) (near the end of the page).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regex flavor there is probably a way to activate multiline mode. In this case, `^` and `$` match line beginnings and endings in addition to the start and end of the whole string.

```
/^-.*$\n((^-.*$\n?)+)/
```

This should match at least two consecutive lines starting with `-`. The first capture/subpattern contains all lines after the first one. So these matches would be what you want to delete.

Of course, replace `\n` with the line ending appropriate for your system.

Comment: [\n\r]+ is a great way of getting the appropriate line-ending on any system.